# Архитектура системы и стуктура проекта на Django и vue.js

Tags: django, vue.js

Как лучше всего постоить архитектуру Django и vue.js ?
Сейчас есть классическая схема работы Django: модель данных, view, template и т.д.

Необходимо создать API (необходим учет версионности API), подключить Vue.js (выбор уже сделан) и все данные из модели данных на стороне клиента получать и обрабатывать через API. В песпективе использование мобильных приложений.

Понятно, что нужно использовать Django REST framework и переписать весь фронт на JS, и нужно как-то подключить npm и собирать JS (пока не разобрался как это сделать)

Сейчас пытаюсь решить вопрос архитектуры системы, как ее лучше постоить?

Comment: Я собираю через webpack, могу ссылку на структуру сбросить. Я строю так: весь фронтенд делаю отдельными компанентами (1 компонент vue может содержать не большую страницу, или страница может собираться из нескольких компонентов vue, это не сложно). Далее все компоненты собираете через сборщик и подключаете собранный файл на индексе фронтенда. В каждом компоненте при его создании (created(), beforeCreate()) Тянете необходимые данные по api и "распихивате" их в нужные места

Comment: Я наверное не очень корректно выразился... Меня в первую очередь интересует как постоить стуктуру проекта. Чтоб потом легче было вносить иземения в код, когда проект разрастется. А ссылку присылайте

Comment: Следуйте проверенным принципам типа DRY, пользуйтесь паттернами и ищите лучшие практики той или иной задачи. Что-то конкретное сказать не могу, т.к. не представляю даже в целой картине что вы собираетесь делать

Comment: А вообще какие бы вам умные ответы не дали, без проб и ошибок не обойтись. Если вы работаете с django, думаю вы знаете что без этого никак. Поищите best practices на выдуманную вами тему

Comment: Если сайт уже работающий, возможно переписывать дороже обойдется. Подключаем к этой же базе еще одну версию django (или версию views) и делаем как нам удобно.